# Bash: regarding loops, arrays and variables

Tags: bash

I hope I am asking this in the right place.

I have a fairly simple bash script that I am working on, however I just started scripting bash a few days ago, and I have hit a bit of a stump.

I have seen familiar questions, but before saying read this, or duplicate, or google, understand I have tried many approaches and I am just stuck with this one roadblock.

I have the following code:

```
find ~/bin/ -type f ! \( -iname '*~' -o -iname '.*' \) -exec basename {} \; | sort | while read line; do
let i=i+1
command_array[$i]="$line"
echo "$i : ${command_array[$i]}"
done

echo $i
echo "array check : ${command_array[*]}"
```

I would like to get those variables from the loop. As I've read, it seems that somehow I need to make those variables before the pipes ? I am not sure how to accomplish this with my current code. It's a combination of: I am not sure how to restructure the code to find files to accommodate this. It looks like the foolowing is what I should be trying to acheive:

```
n=0
printf %s "$foo" |
while IFS= read -r line; do
n=$(($n + 1))
done
echo $n
```

And while I partially understand what's going on here, I am still lost as to how to start to switch what I have to something like this to get variables.

I'm not looking for someone to re-code it for me, but some tips, or hints in getting this going in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to avoid the subshell when using a `while read` loop to consume command output is to rewrite it to redirect from process substition.

Instead of:

```
foo | bar | while read baz; do (( i++ )); done
echo "$i"  # Unset
```

use

```
while read baz; do (( i++ )); done <   <(foo | bar)
echo "$i"  # Works
```

PS: [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically warns about this, and links to a page with documentation on how to restructure a while loop like this.

Comment: Wonderful site! Thanks for the information sir, it will be very helpful in figuring this out.

Comment: With a little guidance from that site there and your comment, it clicked! Haha, was working on that for hours, thanks!